# Dual Basis, Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the ordered basis $B=\{1,x-1,x^2+1\}$ of polynomials of degree $2$ or less, find the dual basis. Am I supposed to write the basis vectors in their canonical form first i.e.. $[1,0,0],[-1,1,0],[1,0,1]$?

Any hints or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a preferred inner product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix having as columns the coefficients of the polynomials in $B$ relative to the canonical basis of $\Bbb R_2[x]$ is:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

If $Q$ denotes the matrix having as columns the coefficients of the vectors in the dual basis of $B$, relative to the canonical basis of the dual space $\Bbb R_2^*[x]$ of $\Bbb R_2 [x]$, then:

$$Q= (P^{-1})^T$$

So, you just need to invert and transpose.

**Added:**

You should get:

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This means that the dual basis of $B$ is: $B^* = \{f_1, f_2,f_3\}$, where:

$$\begin{cases} f_1 = e_1^* + e_2^* - e_3^* \\ f_2 = e_2^* \\ f_3 = e_3^* \end{cases}$$

Where: $e_i^*: \Bbb R_2[x] \to \Bbb R$, $(a_1 \times 1 + a_2 \times x + a_3 \times x^2) \mapsto a_i$

Comment: I get the following functions: $f1$ = [1,-1,1] , $f2$ = [0,1,0] and $f3$ = [0,0,1] what does this mean?